# How do i retrieve a List<Map<String,Object>> from cloud firestore and convert it into a custom model?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The structure of my data looks like this:
[image]

I want to retrieve this data which I have done using this where studentReference is CollectionReference to students collection.
[image]

This returns me this
[image]

Now I want to map this data into a Custom Subject class that looks like this

```
class Subjects {
  int totalAttended;
  int attended;
  int missed;
  final String subjectName;
  final String subjectId;
  final String subjectTeacher;

  Subjects(
      {this.attended,
      this.missed,
      this.totalAttended = 0,
      this.subjectId,
      this.subjectName,
      this.subjectTeacher});
}
```

But can't figure out how to do this mapping. I know I need to use stream but don't know how.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going forward try not to use screenshots when sharing code. Firebase collection is one thing, but your `retreiveData` and the print statement could have easily been embedded code in the post. If somebody wants to help and needs to paste your code into their IDE they're definitely not gonna want to type it out manually.

Anyway, this should get you most of the way there. It should give you the idea at least. By looking at your collection, `Subjects` is a list consisting of 2 maps. So here's a function that iterates through the list, pulls out the key/value pairs from the maps, creates a `Subjects` object out of the values, adds the `Subjects` objects to a list, then returns the list.

```
List<Subjects> getSubjects(List subjectList) {
  final List<Subjects> list = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < subjectList.length; i++) {
    final map = subjectList[i];
    final totalAttended = map['totalAttended'];
    final attended = map['attended'];
    final missed = map['missed'];
    final subjectName = map['subjectName'];
    final subjectId = map['subjectId'];
    final subjectTeacher = map['subjectTeacher'];

    final subject = Subjects(
        totalAttended: totalAttended,
        attended: attended,
        missed: missed,
        subjectName: subjectName,
        subjectTeacher: subjectTeacher,
        subjectId: subjectId);

    list.add(subject);
  }
  return list;
}
```

You can declare a `subjectList` outside of the `retreiveData` function, then where you currently have your print statement, you could do this

```
subjectList = getSubjects(value.data()['subjects']);
```

Then you have a list of `Subjects` objects that you can use as you need to.

Comment: Thank you so much!
will not upload code as screenshot from now on. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.